# Partial LinkField for Sitecore 8.1 rev. 160302

Tags: fieldtype, renderfield

My issue is that I need to be able to allow a user to use the General Link FieldType and when the field is rendered I only want part of the text to be linkable.

Example:

Link Description: This is my link to test please click here

I only want the "click here" portion to be clickable.   Is there any way to do this with the current field types in SiteCore or would I have to create a custom Field Type?

P.S. I wasn't sure how to name my request so I went with Partial LinkField.

Comment: Just feel like adding; "click here" - from an SEO and usability perspective - is a horrible idea.

Comment: We are going to try and convince the customer to do something different but as you know a customer wants what they want regardless of what they are told by us :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not doable with the existing General Link Field.

Your options are:

- Have a Single Line Text field for first part, and generic link for the second part
- Use Rich Text
- Custom Field Type (this is definitely the most complicated options)

I'd recommend first option if this only is needed in a few places. The third option is not trivial, so wouldn't recommend that if you only need this once or twice.